# Sum delivered values and subtract it from the received values with the same name mysql

Tags: mysql

I have this table

table name: com_inv

```
item_name   amount  date_added
item 1      1       06/06/2015
item 2      2       07/06/2015
item 3      3       08/06/2015
item 1      10      09/06/2015
item 2      20      10/06/2015
item 3      30      11/06/2015
```

table name: sls_ordrs

```
item_name   amount  order_status    date_received
item 1      1       received        06/06/2015
item 2      1       delivered   
item 3      2       received        08/06/2015
item 1      5       received        09/06/2015
item 2      5       delivered   
item 3      2       received        11/06/2015
```

What I want to achieve is, per item, subtract the sum of the amount in sls_ordrs that have been "received" from the sum of the amount in com_inv. The resulting table should be like this:

```
Item Name   Stocked Dispensed   Remaining
item 1      11      6           5
item 2      22      0           22
item 3      33      4           29
```

If I use SQL Server, I would just use the CTE but with MySql I need your help. This is the code I came up so far...

```
SELECT
    a.item_name,
    b.stocked AS 'Stocked',
    sum(a.amount) AS 'Dispensed',
    IFNULL(b.stocked, 0) - IFNULL(a.amount, 0) AS 'Remaining'
FROM
    sls_ordrs a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        item_name AS 'item_name',
        SUM(amount) AS 'stocked'
    FROM
        com_inv
    GROUP BY
        item_name
) b ON a.item_name = b.item_name
WHERE
    a.order_status = 'received'
GROUP BY
    item_name
```

The stocked column here gives me a null value.

Comment: what's dispensed supposed to be?

Comment: It's the inventories that have been received.

Comment: Received by the branch that requested it.

Comment: it's still not clear to me where that data comes from, your sample query does not have a a field aliased as dispensed

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion. That Sql syntax is way way incomplete. It's just my feeble attempt in trying to create the query. I don't even know how to begin. Please disregard it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this Query. Hope it should be working fine.

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://rextester.com/ADFB53844)

```
SELECT
    I.item_name,
    I.Stocked,
    S.Dispensed,
    COALESCE (I.Stocked, 0) - COALESCE (S.Dispensed, 0) AS Remaining
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            item_name AS 'item_name',
            SUM(amount) AS 'Stocked'
        FROM
            com_inv
        GROUP BY
            item_name
    ) I
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        item_name,
        order_status,
        SUM(amount) AS Dispensed
    FROM
        sls_ordrs
    WHERE
        order_status = 'received'
    GROUP BY
        item_name
) S ON I.item_name = S.item_name;
```